# Replace given strings in a pdf keeping the original styling

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

Consider the following situation;
I have a pdf containing the following lines -

```
line 1: I love to **write** code
line 2: I love to write *java* code
line 3: I love to write java code that replaces some texts(underline) in pdf.
```

at line 1, `write` is bold having `Arial` font.
at line 2, `java` is italic having `Nunito` font.
at line 3, `texts` is underlined having `Times New Roman` font.

What I am trying to is to replace
`write` with `check`
`java` with `perl`
`texts` with `words`
keeping the exact same font and styling each one has. I have been trying to achieve this using `Itext7` `java` library and gone through a lots of resources on SO, blogs and books but none fulfill my exact requirements.

So far, I can replace given words in a pdf with the same font (if the pdf contain only one font). Though the extracted font size varies from the original, I had to manually put it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
     PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DESTINATION);
     PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

     TextPropertiesExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy = new TextPropertiesExtractionStrategy();
            new PdfCanvasProcessor(extractionStrategy).processPageContent(pdfDocument.getPage(1));
     System.out.println("Font Name: " + extractionStrategy.getFontName());
     System.out.println("Font Size: " + extractionStrategy.getFontSize());
     System.out.println("Text Color: " + extractionStrategy.getTextColor().getColorSpace().toString());

}

private static class TextPropertiesExtractionStrategy implements ITextExtractionStrategy {
        private String fontName;
        private float fontSize;
        private Color textColor;
        private PdfFont font;

        @Override
        public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
            if (data instanceof TextRenderInfo) {
                TextRenderInfo textRenderInfo = (TextRenderInfo) data;

                // Get font information
                font = textRenderInfo.getFont();
                fontName = font.getFontProgram().getFontNames().getFontName();
                fontSize = textRenderInfo.getFontSize();

                // Get text color information
                textColor = textRenderInfo.getFillColor();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getResultantText() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getFontName() {
            return fontName;
        }

        public float getFontSize() {
            return fontSize;
        }

        public PdfFont getFont() {
            return font;
        }

        public Color getTextColor() {
            return textColor;
        }
    }
```

I am open to any other open source libraries or languages as well like python [I've also tried MuPdf] as long as it solves this particular problem.

Comment: Maybe you also need to replace strnigs with strings  (your question title)

Comment: @JoSSte nice catch. too many replacements happening here.

Comment: "I am open to any other open source libraries or languages as well" - that is not how Stack Overflow works. It is your responsibility to choose the technologies before asking; we don't do recommendations, and we don't show how to do the same thing in multiple languages in the same question (unless it's in a totally language-agnostic way) - because it fundamentally is a separate question for each language.

Comment: "So far, I can replace given words in a pdf with the same font (if the pdf contain only one font). Though the extracted font size varies from the original, I had to manually put it." - yes, this sort of thing is inherent to PDF. A PDF file, in general, **does not really contain** "lines", and it's not designed to represent data in any usable, structured way. it's designed to make things look nice on a printed page. As far as PDF is concerned, a "character" is just another graphical element. As such, the question can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: If you have the **original** (!) fonts used in the PDF, then you can achieve your goal using PyMuPDF. The fonts in the PDF itself are subset fonts (99% probability) and thus do not contain the original full character set. Given that, erase the original text via redaction annotation after you have extracted enough original information (like font size, insertion point). Then insert the replacement text using the respective original fonts, insertion points, font sizes, and potentially also text colors. Relatively straightforward in PyMuPDF.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `As such, the question can't be answered in its current form` - this also an answer that, the problem I am stating has no solution under the given circumstances.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `it fundamentally is a separate question for each language` - some libraries have better support than other; this is a common notion. People working with pdf for a long time knows the differences. Assuming that, I asked about the libraries in addition. Otherwise asking the same question in at least 2 different language would led me to more down votes I guess :/ . Although I can't reason myself why this question is downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring language the way a PDF is constructed generally does not lend itself to native editing of components. An editor needs to basically replace existing entries and write fresh content. Take the first change where `w r it e` needs altering to `check`. That "should be easy" it is not an embedded font and is the same number of binary digits (bytes), what could possibly go wrong ?

[image: c]

[image]

So the font placements are totally upset by the changed character width of a proportional font thus an edit needs to treat the whole text block as totally new.

Alright let's change the block styling, and instantly we see why you cannot simply replace letters in styled fonts as they will not be placed at the correct spacing.

[image]

*Java* is more straight forward but it is an embedded font so if a letter in not included you will either see a box or a blank.

[image]

And since it is a PDF `texts` is not the same as `words`, so note the line under is totally a different object (there are no underline fonts) and needs a totally separate edit.

[image]

Thus the most efficient way to alter PDF text is using a heads up GUI word processor where both those disruptions, and others, can be compensated for by human judgments.

Comment: Knowing that this can't be done in a programmatic way, saves me a lot of time. Otherwise I would still be investing my time searching for a soln.

Comment: I was wondering why `pdf in action` book doesn't have this kind of text manipulating section in it. Now it make sense.

Comment: correction - `iText in Action`